# How to prevent the user from accessing anything other than the app running on public exposed device?

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications

I've a web app that must prevent users from accessing anything else than the application itself that is currently running on the device. Why? The device is exposed to the community and despite of being docked with a protection there are always some features that we can still access such as the settings pull down menu.

Android devices typically exposes 5 different areas of interaction that can "manipulate" the device which are:

- pull down settings
- the home button (press and long press)
- the power button
- the recents button (http://developer.android.com/design/handhelds/index.html)

Until the user access a admin panel were he types a secret close to close the app the app must no be closed.

Is there a way to achieve this natively or via phonegap (maybe some plugins out there)? 
I know that phonegap already fires events for `home` and `backbutton` as you can see here but i need more.

**The list of supported events:**
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after digging a little bit into the subject i found this great article that explains the approach to run [android in kiosk](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) mode